# Установка PCRE при помощи двух bash-скриптов

Tags: bash

[PCRE](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html)

Нужно установить данную библиотеку, хочется это сделать через два bash-скрипта (дополнительно повысить образовательный уровень)

Первая часть установки библиотеки:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr                 \
        --docdir=/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.44 \
        --enable-unicode-properties       \
        --enable-pcre16                   \
        --enable-pcre32                   \
        --enable-pcregrep-libz            \
        --enable-pcregrep-libbz2          \
        --enable-pcretest-libreadline     \
        --disable-static                 && make
```

Вторая часть установки:

```
make install  &&   mv -v /usr/lib/libpcre.so.* /lib &&.  ln -sfv ../../lib/$(readlink /usr/lib/libpcre.so) /usr/lib/libpcre.so
```

Пытаюсь сделать два bash скрипта из этих кодов

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/name/PCRE_folder/ ./configure --prefix.....(далее код первой части)
```

этот pcre_conf.sh нормально выполняется и конфигурирование проходит на "Ура"

Далее потаюсь по аналогии сделать второй скрипт для "make install", но не получается

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/name/PCRE_folder/ && make install && mv .... (далее код из второго блока)
```

сохраняю в pcre_inst.sh, пытаюсь запустить (**./pcre_inst.sh**), а мне в ответ типа: /home/name/PCRE_folder/: Is a directory

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать bash-скрипт, чтобы он выполнял вторую часть

Спасибо!

Comment: `cd /home/name/PCRE_folder/` вместо `/home/name/PCRE_folder/` что бы перейти в каталог, так как попытка выполнения каталога возвращает код возврата отличный от 0, то далее команды не выполняются.

Comment: а в первом скрипте "pcre_conf.sh"  - cd указывать не надо
Всё и так работает

Во втором пробовал указать в начале строки cd, но всё равно скрипт отказывался выполняться.

Comment: а вот если "ручками" ввести вторую часть "make install" через командную строку, то всё выполняется.

Как-бы это в bash-скрипт внедрить, чтобы ручками не вводить?

Comment: Ничего лучшего не нашёл, как объединить оба файла в один
Тогда сборка происходит нормально, но хотелось бы найти решение для двух файлов

Answer (score 0):

Решение своей задачи я нашёл только такое:

две части кода объединяются в одну и получается скрипт такого вида:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/name/PCRE/pcre-8.44/ && ./configure --prefix..... и далее код обоих частей
```

нужно было через **&&** выполнить объединение